# Blend modes with transparency? (i.e, fireballs, effects, hitsparks.)

Tags: blend-modes

Is it possible to do transparent meshes with blend modes, like this?
[image]

Add/addition mode in image editors and game engines looks like this. When shapes overlap, it gets brighter, and dark colors are not visible.
[image]

Comment: Hello, yes you can, what difficulty have you met?

Comment: Yes. Bonus: use alpha hashed for best results where one transparent thing is in front of another in the same mesh object.

Comment: I don't know how to do it at all, I only know how to apply transparency, not blend modes like add.

Comment: what effect would you like to do exactly? maybe give a precise example

Comment: Like in the image above. A texture applied to a plane, and it's displayed over top of things like it would be in image editing software set to add, multiply, etc mode.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** So as you've reformulated your question it looks like my answer is not correct anymore, anyway I leave it as it is.

If you're talking about the light beams, here is what you can do:

[image]

It's a *ColorRamp* plugged into an *Emission* that goes on the Z axis. Also you need to put a transparent gradient and some noise. Don't forget to go into the *Material* panel > *Settings* and *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*:

[image]

You can transform the shape with a *Lattice* modifier for example.

Comment: That's close but it's not the same effect. I need to be able to use textures, and add mode looks different than setting something to emissive.

Comment: hello, please edit your question and be as much precise as possible in your question, it lacks precision for the moment imho

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: You see the list of modes in the color mix node? Those are all ways of displaying one color over another. They all handle how the colors blend differently. All of them are different than taking a transparent image and making it brighter/produce light.

Comment: It's just blend modes, it's not really a specific effect. If you go into photoshop or other image editing software and set a layer to "add" or "addition", that's what it is.

Comment: ok so it's how the emissions of different planes cumulate?

Comment: Yeah,
https://i.gyazo.com/3338e1988ab7470b4793cc37a635f317.png

Comment: Well actually, no, there is no emission involved in the literal sense. Blend modes just effect how the colors interact in general.

Comment: you can do it within the same material with the different MixRGB node modes, I don't know if you can do it with separate planes

Comment: That said, it doesn't seem easy within one material either, I hope someone will tell... it must be possible through the Compositor but it will be tedious, it all depends on your scene I guess